# Java invoke Sqoop fails on hive import

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a Java Program which run a Sqoop operation by `Sqoop.runTool()` method. Until now, I can successfully run this operation to get data from oracle to HDFS.
but when I add the parameter `--hive-import`, it reports an warning in hive's log file in `/tmp/root/hive.log`:

> hive-site.xml not found on CLASSPATH

Mean while I noticed that,run by JavaAPI and by plain sqoop Command，the console message have a different output:

1. Logging initialized musing configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hive-exec-1.1.0!hive-log4j.properties
2. Logging initialized musing configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hive-common-1.1.0!hive-log4j.properties

Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: add `/etc/hive/conf` to your Java CLASSPATH *(yes, the directory -- Hadoop `Configuration` instances scan the CLASSPATH for directories, then scan these directories for the hard-coded conf file names. Just like Log4J does by default)*

Comment: Thanks, but when I add this directory to `CLASSPATH`,either by set environment variable or as additional parameter of  `java -cp` , I still get  the same error.